# How do I overwrite the variable from cleaned_data

Tags: python, django, django-views

I wanted to know how I can save a photo that will contain a watermark. Currently grabs a photo from the form and creates a watermark on it, but saves it separately. More precisely, I would like the photo I send in the form to be processed and saved.

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_w = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form_w.is_valid():
            form = form_w.save(commit=False)
            cd = form_w.cleaned_data['img']
            im = Image.open(cd)
            width, height = im.size

            draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
            text = "TEST WATERMARK"

            font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 36)
            textwidth, textheight = draw.textsize(text, font)


            margin = 10
            x = width - textwidth - margin
            y = height - textheight - margin


            draw.text((x, y), text, font=font)

            im.save('Luki/media/upload_p/{}'.format(cd))

            form.save()

            return redirect('Luki:gallery')
    else:
        form = ImageForm()
    return render(request, 'Luki/upload_img.html', {
        'form': form,

    })
```

Comment: What processing do you want to do exactly? In order to save the image you can create a separate method.

Comment: wants to process the image that is being sent by the form. I am sending an image some_image.jpg then a watermark is added and it is saved as some_image.jpg.

Answer (score 1):

Use ‘form.instance.save()’ instead of ‘form.save()’ as instance is the object bounded to the form

Comment: Tried using `form.img.save()` but still don't know how to upload a watermarked photo there

Comment: form.instance.save()

Comment: then I have a message `'ImageModel' object has no attribute 'instance'`

Comment: form_w.instance.save()

Comment: It doesn't work like that. I need to upload the photo somehow after calling `im.save('Luki/media/upload_p/{}'. Format (cd))` 
When i use `form_w.instance.save()` it saves the picture but the original from the form and not the watermarked one

Answer (score 0):

The saved file that I assigned to the
`img = Image.open(('Luki/media/upload_p/{}'.format(cd)))` variable has this format
`<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=1920x1080 at 0x5823C10>`
. I can convert it somehow so that it can be read as a photo.jpg ?